# separate media queries for every class?

Tags: css, media-queries

Will it make the site slower if I make a separate media query for every class?

I mean to write

```
.class1 {
   /* rules */
}  

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .class1 {
     /* rules */
  }
}

.class2 {
 /* rules */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .class2 {
     /* rules */
  }
}
```

Instead of (which I see everywhere)

```
.class1 {
   /* rules */
}

.class2 {
   /* rules */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .class1 {
     /* rules */
  }
  .class2 {
     /* rules */
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the point of dividing and repeating a "mediaquery" for the same resolution?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini, so I immediately see the full class definition and can correct it in all the places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having multiple media queries shouldn't impact performance. But in case your project will scale then and adding many queries will increase the size of the CSS file, which could impact site's performance.

Comment: so it's just that the first solution will produce more code (repeating `,@media only screen and (max-width: 800px)`) which user has to load, right?